# Message "You haven't entered an issue number" displayed on every commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Whenever i do a check-in from TortoiseSVN, a message as shown in the below screenshot is displayed.

[image: You haven't entered an issue number]

After clicking on *Proceed* without an issue number, it will do the commit. I am not sure how I can avoid this message or how to provide an issue number while committing.

Can anybody provide both kinds of solutions?

Below is the screenshot of the issue tracker integration properties

[image]

Below is the screenshot of Edit BugTraq Properties

[image]

Comment: Is your project integrated with bug tracker? Right click on your working copy folder -> Tortoise SVN -> Properties. In `Properties` dialog, do you see `bugtraq` property? If so, read a bit about it here: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html.

Comment: Yes i see something which is integrated with some bug tracker. I have been through the SVN link which you gave but cannot understand anything from it

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of `Edit Bugtraq Properties` dialog?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Your regex properties are in the wrong format, or in the wrong location, or both. [According to the TortoiseSVN bugtraq documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html), the regular expression property is either two strings separated by newline, or one string. For the one-string method, you need to capture *only* the bug ID in a capture group; for the two-string method, the first regex captures a string containing a bug ID, the second extracts the actual bug ID from the strings extracted by the first regex. You have one regular expression that wraps several items in capture groups, including the entire matched string. If you actually want to match the entire ALMCRxx string as a bug ID with a single regex, you may need to use some non-capturing groups, like `((?:ALM|alm)(?:cr|CR|rq|RQ)\w+)`.

If you don't want the entire string as a bug ID you'll need to adjust the capture groups, or use the two-regex method.

It looks like if you use the second "Bug-ID expression" box in the dialog, you will always be using the 2-string method. So in your case, you have entered a regex to extract the bug ID from matched strings, but you have no pattern entered to match the strings in the first place. Thus TortoiseSVN will never find any bug string.

Clicking the little empty button beside the regex edit boxes, allows you to test your regex on a commit message. If I put your regex into the "Message part expression" box instead of the "Bug-ID expression", strings like ALMCR55 highlight in the sample commit message. Nothing highlights if I leave it in the "Bug-ID expression" edit box where you have it.

I'm not sure whether you need a second string or not to extract a piece of the ALMCR55 text, but at the very least you'll need to have something in the "Message part expression".

Answer (score 1):

You have arbitrary text that will be **parsed by regex inside your commit message** `(Bug-Id expression): ((ALM|alm)(CR|RQ|cr|rq)\w+)`. For example, this will work:

```
- here is my issue fix: ALMCR55
```

As you can see, `ALM`, `CR` and `55` are present in your commit message. TortoiseSVN should also highlight this text in your commit message.

Now the only thing you have to figure out yourself is where to get the bug ID from (I guess from your bug tracker).

Comment: I tried with the log message "here is my issue fix: ALMCR55" when committing but still the same popup message is shown "You haven't entered an issue number". what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is `ALMCR55` converted to hyperlink in TortoiseSVN commit message dialog? It should turn blue and become clickable. Which version of TortoiseSVN are you using?

Comment: No it did not turn into blue nor it is clickable. Below is my tortoise SVN version info

TortoiseSVN 1.8.8, Build 25755 - 64 Bit and Subversion 1.8.10

Comment: One (unlikely) thing to check: does `Bug-Id expression` has any `space` chars at the end? Please go to https://www.regex101.com/ and test your `Bug-Id expression` regex along with the `ALMCR55` value, if it matches, then TortoiseSVN is not recognizing it and it looks like bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Preliminary Note:** The following answers apply to a current (in 2023) version of Tortoise **Git**, where this issue can also happen. I am not sure how far it applies to SVN, but since the Tortoise UI is very similar for both, I figure it might also help with this

### Avoiding the issue

1. Open the Git Settings
2. Go to "Hook Scrips" > "Issue Tracker Config"
3. In "Config source", select the desired scope ("Project" if you just want to disable it for this project, or "Global" if you want it disabled for all projects)
4. In the "BugTraq"-Section, empty all the typeable fields and make sure all the `☐ inherited` boxes are *not* checked, and set all the dropdown fields to "false"
5. Check under "Effective" that those fields are now empty, then click OK

=> The message should now no longer appear

### Providing an Issue Number when committing

This is assuming that your issues can be found under an Address like: http://my.bugtracker.address/KEY-1234

1. As before, navigate to "Hook Scrips" > "Issue Tracker Config" and select the desired scope
2. In the "BugTraq"-Section, under `bugtraq.url`, write the URL like this: http://my.bugtracker.address/KEY-%BUGID%
3. In the same section, under `bugtrack.message`, write: %BUGID%
4. Set all the dropdown fields to "true"

=> Now, the Tortoise Git Commit window should have a "BUG-ID/Issue-Nr"-field in the top right corner that you can provide the Issue Number in, and if this field is not filled, then the warning message from the question will pop up